# multiple separator in a string python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
text="Brand.*/Smart Planet.#/Color.*/Yellow.#/Type.*/Sandwich Maker.#/Power Source.*/Electrical."
```

I have this kind of string. I am facing the problem which  splits it to 2 lists. Output will be approximately like this :

```
name = ['Brand','Color','Type','Power Source']
value = ['Smart Plane','Yellow','Sandwich Maker','Electrical']
```

Is there any solution for this.

Comment: What is your current non-optimal solution?

Comment: @Sayse sorry i asked the question wrongly . i updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
name = []
value = []

text = text.split('.#/')

for i in text:
    i = i.split('.*/')
    name.append(i[0])
    value.append(i[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `re.split` and `list` slicing.

**Ex:**

```
import re
text="Brand.*/Smart Planet.#/Color.*/Yellow.#/Type.*/Sandwich Maker.#/Power Source.*/Electrical."

data = [i for i in re.split("[^A-Za-z\s]+", text) if i]
name = data[::2]
value = data[1::2]
print(name)
print(value)
```

**Output:**

```
['Brand', 'Color', 'Type', 'Power Source']
['Smart Planet', 'Yellow', 'Sandwich Maker', 'Electrical']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to split the text, and populate the lists in a loop.
Using regex you protect your code from invalid input.

```
import re 
name, value = [], []

for ele in re.split(r'\.#\/', text):
     k, v = ele.split('.*/')
     name.append(k)
     value.append(v)

>>> print(name, val)
['Brand', 'Color', 'Type', 'Power Source'] ['Smart Planet', 'Yellow', 'Sandwich Maker', 'Electrical.']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text="Brand.*/Smart Planet.#/Color.*/Yellow.#/Type.*/Sandwich Maker.#/Power Source.*/Electrical."
name=[]
value=[]
word=''
for i in range(len(text)):
    temp=i
    if text[i]!='.' and text[i]!='/' and text[i]!='*' and text[i]!='#':
        word=word+''.join(text[i])
    elif temp+1<len(text) and temp+2<=len(text):
        if text[i]=='.' and text[temp+1]=='*' and text[temp+2]=='/':
            name.append(word)
            word=''
        elif text[i]=='.' and text[temp+1]=='#' and text[temp+2]=='/':
            value.append(word)
            word=''
    else:
        value.append(word)

print(name)
print(value)
```

this will be work...